# Need help in Exists clause with or keyword

Tags: sql, exists

i am trying to change the IN clause with EXISTS clause but not getting the desired results

OLD SCRIPT

```
delete from ABC a 
where column1 IN (select DISTINCT column1 
                  from BCD b 
                  where b.column2 = a.column2 
                      and b.column3 = 'N')
   or a.column3 = "Y";
```

when i am changing this to

```
delete from ABC a 
where EXISTS (select column1 
              from BCD b 
              where b.column2 = a.column2 
              and b.column3 = 'N')
   or a.column3 = "Y";
```

i am not getting the desired results i have doubt that it is due to **"or"** condition used in the last.
Need help to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not due to OR condition.
Your OLD script is validating the values against COLUMN1

```
where column1 IN (select DISTINCT column1 from BCD b where b.column2=a.column2 and b.column3= 'N')
```

But, the other script checks if any records exist in the subquery.

```
where EXISTS (select column1 from BCD b where b.column2=a.column2 and b.column3= 'N')
```

To summarize, query with **IN** verifies the existence of returned values in column1, while **EXISTS** just checks if the subquery returns 0 or more rows.

Comment: Hi Prateek  Thanks for the clarification.can you please help me to rewrite with exists as the in clause is taking more time to complete

Comment: Can you explain to me the scenario ? what are you trying to achieve?
And how both the tables are related?

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `column1` filter. Remember that the projected column in an exists subquery isn’t doing anything - you’re only checking that the subquery returns rows, not what they are. I typically use `select null` in (not) exists to make this obvious to the reader

```
delete from ABC a 
where EXISTS
 (select null 
  from BCD b 
  where b.column2=a.column2 
  And b.column1 = a.column1
  and b.column3= 'N')
or a.column3= "Y";
```